# http 400 bad request when using date - Spring MVC, pickadate.js

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, post

I have a simple form with 3 fields, one containing a pickadate(), the other a pickatime() and the last a simple number.

When I try to post my form, I get a bad request error.

**Request dedails**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/CapTheater/admin/addProjection
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 Mauvaise Requête
```

Request Headers

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:39
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:JSESSIONID=EA0DDBF444BC5A4CA416715D72FF9D71
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/CapTheater/showMovie/1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36
```

Form Data

```
day:2014-01-01
date:09:30
place_nbr:0
```

Response Headers

```
Connection:close
Content-Length:986
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 30 Dec 2013 23:35:24 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

**Here is the form :**

```
<form:form method="post" action="../admin/addProjection" id="add_movie_form">
    <form:label id="dayLabel" path="day">Date : </form:label>
    <form:input type="text" id="dayInput" path="day" />
    <form:label id="startLabel" path="date">Start : </form:label>
    <form:input type="text" id="startInput" path="date" />
    <form:label id="sizeLabel" path="place_nbr">Steats availables : 
    <form:input type="text" id="sizeInput" path="place_nbr" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"value="Save" />
</form:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        $("#dayInput").pickadate({
            format : 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            min : new Date()
        });
        $("#startInput").pickatime({
            format : 'HH:i',
            min: [8, 0],
            max: [22, 30]
        });
    </script>
```

**The controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "admin/addProjection", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addProjection(
@ModelAttribute("command") final Projection projection,
    final ModelMap model)
{
        projectionDao.save(projection);
        return "/showMovie/" + projection.getMovieId() + "#tabs-4";
}
```

**Finally, in the bean**

```
public class Projection implements Comparable<Projection>
{
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM/dd")
    private Date day;
    public Date getDay()
    {
        return day;
    }

    public void setDay(Date day)
    {
        this.day = day;
    }
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Check the body of the request you are making and post it here. Use firebug or chrome developer tools.

Comment: Any reason why your form action is `../admin/addProjection` and not `/action/addProjection`?

Comment: Because my controller answer to myApp/admin/addProjection
I don't know the prefix /action/

I saw there are some mistakes in my project, for example I have controllers answering to something/... and not /something/... and I think it is the cause of some problems I had.

I solved my problem by bindig a string representation of my date and not the date object directly.

PS: After many research it seemed the ":" in the hour caused a problem too, I simply removed it